Error Adding Coroutines to Kotlin Multiplaform Project
I am learning Kotlin Multiplatform and am trying to add Coroutines to commonMain, as described in the documentation link
Screenshot from kotlinx.coroutines
Repository

The documentation in the repository says to add this to the list of dependencies in this way.



Am I missing something? 


IntelliJ Screenshot:

Language Version: kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.9.21"

you may need kotlin 2.0.0 for 1.9.0

Reducing the dependency to version 1.8.0 appears to resolve all issues.
